# Wifi adapter sometimes not detected!

Tags: drivers, wireless, kubuntu, iwlwifi, firmware

I am using Kubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10. About 40% of the time I boot into Kubuntu, it doesn't detect a wifi adapter and I have to reboot. After reboot it detects the adapter. If I boot another OS from USB, the same happens and after rebooting it works fine. So is my wifi card not properly compatible with linux?
[Result of dmesg | grep wifi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnf0X.png)

[My driver manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiTNa.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Could this be the problem? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Windows Fast Start feature. Windows doesn't fully shut down with this feature enabled.